# Idiomatic way to check if any elements in a polars DataFrame are null

Tags: python-polars

Is there a more idiomatic way than:

`df.select(pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().null_count()))[0, 0]`

to check if any elements in a polars DataFrame `df` are null?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Just learned of [`.has_validity`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.has_validity.html#polars.Series.has_validity) from [@alexander-beedie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18224096/alexander-beedie)

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10870#issuecomment-1704007984

> FYI: the fastest way to check if a series has nulls is `col.has_validity()`

```py
>>> any(col.has_validity() for col in df)
True
```

---

**Original answer:**

Perhaps [`DataFrame.null_count()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.null_count.html#polars.DataFrame.null_count)

```py
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1, None, 2], "bar": [None, 3, 4]})
>>> sum(df.null_count()).item()
2
```

[`.item()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.item.html#polars.DataFrame.item) can be used instead of `[0, 0]`

Comment: I guess `df.null_count().pipe(sum).item()` isn't the worst thing in the world...

Comment: If `has_validity=False`, then there are definitely no nulls, but if `has_validity=True`, there may still be no nulls, since every entry of the validity bitmask may be `False`. If you can edit your answer to clarify that, I'd be happy to accept it.